# Count from 1 to n in Negabinary and Negaquaternary

Tags: code-golf, counting, base-conversion

Instead of normal binary, you must count from 1 to an input in **negabinary concatenated to negaquaternary**.

Here's an example, put in the form of an array:

```
[11, 1102, 1113, 100130, 101131, 11010132, 11011133, 11000120, 11001121, 11110122, 11111123, 11100110, 11101111, 10010112, 10011113, 10000100, 10001101, 10110102, 10111103, 10100230, 10101231, 1101010232, 1101011233, 1101000220, 1101001221, 1101110222, 1101111223, 1101100210, 1101101211, 1100010212, 1100011213, 1100000200, 1100001201, 1100110202, 1100111203, 1100100330, 1100101331, 1111010332, 1111011333, 1111000320, 1111001321, 1111110322, 1111111323, 1111100310, 1111101311, 1110010312, 1110011313, 1110000300, 1110001301, 1110110302, 1110111303, 111010013030, 111010113031, 100101013032, 100101113033, 100100013020, 100100113021, 100111013022, 100111113023, 100110013010, 100110113011, 100001013012, 100001113013, 100000013000, 100000113001, 100011013002, 100011113003, 100010013130, 100010113131, 101101013132, 101101113133, 101100013120, 101100113121, 101111013122, 101111113123, 101110013110, 101110113111, 101001013112, 101001113113, 101000013100, 101000113101, 101011013102, 101011113103, 101010013230, 101010113231, 11010101013232, 11010101113233, 11010100013220, 11010100113221, 11010111013222, 11010111113223, 11010110013210, 11010110113211, 11010001013212, 11010001113213, 11010000013200, 11010000113201, 11010011013202, 11010011113203, 11010010013330]
```

Your program must produce those numbers in any of these forms:

- spaced apart
- in an array
- on new lines

#### How do I get those numbers?

Integer `n` will be used as an example of input.

```
for i := 1 to n
    print "i in base -2" + "i in base -4"
```

#### Rules:

- You can submit a function or a whole program
- You can go from 0 or 1 to the input
- Builtins are allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [O](http://o.readthedocs.org/), 18 bytes

```
j){n.2_bo4_bo' o}d
```

Just my own take on this. Prints numbers with a space between them.

[Try it online](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/code=j)%7Bn.2_bo4_bo%27+o%7Dd&input=7)

Explanaiton:

```
j)                 Increment input by 1
  {             }d Do this (input+1) times
   n.2_bo          Convert n to base -2 and output
         4_bo      Convert n to base -4 and output
             ' o   Output a space
```

Answer (score 5):

### Python - 83 bytes

```python
f=lambda i,k:i and f(-i/k,k)+`-i%k`or''
i=0;exec"i-=1;print f(i,2)+f(i,4);"*input()
```

`f` is a function that converts (the negation of) an integer *i* to a negative base *2 ≤ k ≤ 10*. Input is taken from stdin.

---

**Sample Usage**

```python
$ echo 30 | python nega2+4.py
11
1102
1113
100130
101131
11010132
11011133
11000120
11001121
11110122
11111123
11100110
11101111
10010112
10011113
10000100
10001101
10110102
10111103
10100230
10101231
1101010232
1101011233
1101000220
1101001221
1101110222
1101111223
1101100210
1101101211
1100010212
```

Comment: I love your for loop workaround :D

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>124</s> <s>81</s> 73 bytes

```matlab
n->(a=2863311530;b=3435973836;[base(2,(i+a)$a)*base(4,(i+b)$b)for i=1:n])
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an integer and returns an array. Each element of the array is a successive number between 1 and *n* in negabinary concatenated to itself in negaquaternary.

The negabinary representation of an integer can be computed using Schroppel's shortcut:

```matlab
base(2, (i + 2863311530) $ 2863311530)
```

For an integer *i*, this is *i* + 2863311530, XOR 2863311530, encoded in base 2. The negaquaternary shortcut is similar:

```matlab
base(4, (i + 3435973836) $ 3435973836)
```

Comment: as per this meta ruling, you can define globals with the constants outside: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5532/when-submitting-a-function-can-global-variables-be-declared-outside-the-functio

Comment: @Maltysen: Oh nice, I had forgotten about that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can define globals unless the function is named.

Comment: @feersum: Okay, no problem. Made them local at the cost of 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <strike>31</strike> <strike>30</strike> <strike>29</strike> 27 bytes

Uses [Forumla by D. Librik (Szudzik)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#Calculation) (look at negabinary and quaternary sections). Can probably be golfed a bit.

```
VQjksjVmx+NKi*8d16K"AC",2 4
```

Prints from zero on separate lines.

```
VQ                   For i in 0-Q
 jk                  Join by empty string
  s                  Sum of two arrays
   jV                Vectorized base conversion
    m       "AC"     Map of A and C
     x               Bitwise xor
      +NK            Sum of loop var and constant inline assigned
       i  16         To base 10 from 16
        *8           String repetition times 8
         d           Map var
      K              Xnor of constant
   ,2 4              Bases 2 and 4
```

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQjksjVmx%2BNKi*8d16K%22AC%22%2C2+4&input=10&debug=1).

Comment: @AlexA. "You can go from 0 or 1 to the input"

Comment: Wow, clearly I'm oblivious. Sorry, false alarm!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

I think this can be golfed further. Counts from 0.

```
li),{_[CA]{:Ba8*Gb_@+^B8-b\}/N}/
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li)%2C%7B_%5BCA%5D%7B%3ABa8*Gb_%40%2B%5EB8-b%5C%7D%2FN%7D%2F&input=10).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
bF¥€Ø½ḤN¤Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//YkbCpeKCrMOYwr3huKROwqThuIz///8xMDA)

### How it works

```
bF¥€Ø½ḤN¤Ḍ - Main link. Takes an integer as left argument
    Ø½ḤN¤  - Yield the list [-2, -4]:
        ¤  -   Group the previous commands into a constant:
    Ø½     -     Start with [1, 2] (builtin constant)
      Ḥ    -     Double     [2, 4]
       N   -     Negate     [-2, -4]
  ¥€       - Generate the range 1...n and do the following to each:
b          -   Convert to bases -2 and -4
           -   For example, 5b[-2, -4] => [[1, 0, 1], [1, 3, 1]]
 F         -   Flatten the lists          [1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1]
         Ḍ -   Convert to a number        101131
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Output is an array of digit arrays.

```
õìJÑ)ícUõì4n
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9exK0SntY1X17DRu&input=MTAKLVE)